# Checking if a string is valid with special chars

Tags: sql-server, string, special-characters, patindex

I'm using `PATINDEX` to validate if a column has invalid special chars. But I'm facing some problems with some chars.

```
SELECT PATINDEX(N'%[^a-zA-Z0-9 !"&''()*+,-./:;?=%~@[]_{}\|<>]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, 'abc╢123' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN)
```

The valid chars are `! " & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; ? = % ~ @ [ ] _ { } \ | < >`.

The `╢` is not one of the valid chars but PATINDEX still returns 0.

Is there another way to validate that?

Comment: Ugh escaping the `[` and `]` with `PATINDEX` is always a nightmare.

Comment: I wish `^` was an allowed character!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping is one method.
But if you just want to ignore the readable [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters, then the range could be simplified.

`[^ -~]` : not between space and `~`

```
-- Sample data
declare @T table (col NVARCHAR(30) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN primary key);
insert into @T (col) values
(N'abc╢123'),
(N'xyz123[}'''),
(N'abc௹123');

-- Query
SELECT col, PATINDEX(N'%[^ -~]%' collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, col) as pos
FROM @T;
```

**Returns:**

```
col         pos
--------    ----
abc╢123     4
abc௹123     4
xyz123[}'   0
```

But to also locate the caret and some others, it's more complicated.
Since PATINDEX doesn't have ESCAPE as LIKE does.

```
-- Sample data
declare @T table (
 id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
 col NVARCHAR(30) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN
 );
insert into @T (col) values
 (N'xyz[123]}''') -- good
 ,(N'abc╢123') -- bad
,(N'abc௹123') -- bad
,(N'def#456') -- bad
,(N'def^456') -- bad
;

-- also locate #, ´ , ` and ^
SELECT col, 
CASE 
WHEN PATINDEX(N'%[^ !"$-_a-z{-~]%' collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, col) > 0
THEN PATINDEX(N'%[^ !"$-_a-z{-~]%' collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, col) 
ELSE CHARINDEX(N'^' collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, col)
END AS pos
FROM @T;
```

**Returns:**

```
xyz[123]}'  0
abc╢123     4
abc௹123     4
def#456     4
def^456     4
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But I have tested this expression and in fact, the char `╢` is found in with PATINDEX. I also tried with another char `௹` and your expression is not working. I can still use an invalid char.

`SELECT PATINDEX('%[^ -~]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, 'abc௹123')`

Comment: Doesn't work for `௹`? Okay... that's odd.  Probably something to do with that collation...

Comment: Ok, `SELECT PATINDEX('%[^ -~]%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, N'abc௹123')` does return 4.  The varchar `'௹'` translates to '?', while the nvarchar `N'௹'` doesn't. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this fixed your answer. And I also believe that your approach is more efficient than the `LIKE` method. 

But I also need to block `#`, `^`, `´` and ```. and all of them are in-between `SPACE` and `~`. And I can't find a way to add those restrictions to your code. Is it possible?

Comment: Aargghh, not being able to use ESCAPE for a PATINDEX is really a pain if you want to include `[` and `]` but not `^`.  Just look at that ASCII map. The problem is with also accepting `]`.  If the caret would be allowed then using a few more ranges would work for those others : `PATINDEX(N'%[^ !"$-_a-z{-~]%' collate  SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN, col)`.

Comment: @jpmo22 Added an extra solution, but I don't really like it... Looks like MS did receive at least one request to allow an escape also for PATINDEX.  But it never gained enough support to implement it. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be caused by `]` in the pattern. You can use `LIKE` operator along with `ESCAPE`. Minimal example:

```
-- valid characters are digits, "[" and "]"
SELECT val
     , expected
     , CASE WHEN val LIKE '%[^0-9[]]%'             THEN 'Bad' ELSE 'Good' END AS wrong_pattern
     , CASE WHEN val LIKE '%[^0-9[\]]%' ESCAPE '\' THEN 'Bad' ELSE 'Good' END AS right_pattern
FROM (VALUES
    ('12345', 'Good'),
    ('[123]', 'Good'),
    ('ABCDE', 'Bad'),
    ('123\5', 'Bad')
) AS t(val, expected)
```

So your pattern could be written as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc╢123!"&''()*+,-./:;?=%~@[]_{}\|<>' NOT LIKE '%[^a-z0-9 [\]\\!"&''()*+,\-./:;?=%~@_{}|<>]%' ESCAPE '\' THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END
```

I escaped `]`, `-` and `\`. The characters `%` and `_` do not behave as wildcards inside square brackets thus not escaped.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can I escape `_` along with other chars? I need to create a case when with all valid chars?

Comment: I am unable to test the pattern in your post but the problem is definitely with `]`. I think you only need to change ``\`` to ``\\`` and `]` to `\]`.